# How to get employees listed under their manager? SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database:

```
Staff   Name
1       Blake
2       Jake

Mgr     Emp
2       6
2       8
3       5
4       7
```

Is it possible to search up all employees but list them under the manager?

> Select all:
>
> ```
> Staff   Name    Mgr
> 1       Blake   null
> 2       Jake    null
> 6       Scott   2
> 8       Jack    2
> 3       Clark   null
> 5       Martin  3
> 4       Smith   null
> 7       Scott   4
> ```

And is there a way to look up the team when a staff is searched?

> Search: "Scott"
>
> Returns:
>
> ```
> Staff   Name    Mgr
> 2       Jake    null
> 6       Scott   2
> 8       Jack    2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have:

- a table "staff" with all the people in the company. For clarity I will rename the "Staff" column to "id".
- a many to many table "staff_manager" to link employees with their managers. For clarity I will rename the "Mgr" column to "manager_id" and the "Emp" to "employee_id".
- all tables named lowercase and plural.

You may do:

```
SELECT employees.id, employees.name, managers.id, managers.name
FROM staff as employees
LEFT JOIN employee_managers ON (employee_managers.employee_id = employees.id)
LEFT JOIN staff as managers ON (managers.id = employee_managers.manager_id)
```

for the second query you add a where clause to the above query:

```
WHERE managers.name = "Scott" OR employees.name = "Scott"
```

> NOTE: If you may change the model of your database, I would suggest to
>   set a UNIQUE constrain on the employee_id of the staff_managers table,
>   so that one employee can have ONLY ONE manager.

Answer (score 0):

http://rextester.com/OAREI7219 is solution

```
CREATE TABLE Managers (
  MgrID int ,
  EmpID int
)

CREATE TABLE Staff (
  EmpID int,
  name nvarchar(50)
)
```

Query is ;

```
SELECT 
    s.EmpID AS Staff,
    s.name AS Name,
    m.MgrID
FROM Staff s LEFT JOIN Managers m ON s.EmpID = m.EmpID ;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

To get All Employees with their managers. Try

```
Select staff.Id,Staff.name,managers.mgr
From staff left join managers on staf.id=managers.emp
```

To search about employee and get his team with the manager also. Try

— Search: 'scott'

```
Select staff.Id,Staff.name,managers.mgr
From staff left join managers on staf.id=managers.emp 
Where managers.mgr =(select t.mgr from managers as t where t.emp='scott')

Union all
Select staff.Id,Staff.name,managers.mgr
From managers left join staff on staf.id=managers.mgr
Where managers.emp='scott'
```